# Deserialize a nested dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, yaml, yamldotnet

I would like to convert a YAML document to an object graph [using YamlDotNet deserializer](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/wiki/Samples.DeserializeObjectGraph). Below is a sample of yhe YAML file.

```
desks:
  - A5
  - A6
  - A7
  - A8
  - ...
employees:
  - E00
  - E10
  - E20
  - ...
schedule:
  0:
    E00: A0
    E10: A1
    E100: A10
    E20: A2
    E30: A3
    E40: A4
    E50: A5
    E60: B0
    E70: F3
    E80: A8
    E90: A9
  1:
    E00: A0
    E10: A1
    E100: A10
    E20: A2
    E30: A3
    E40: A4
    E50: A5
    E60: B0
    E70: F3
    E80: A8
    E90: A9
  ...
```

Following the guide I have linked earlier, I have created a **Scheduler** encapsulating all the nodes of my YAML document to be casted with

```
var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder()
                .WithNamingConvention(CamelCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
                .Build();

var order = deserializer.Deserialize<Scheduler>(input);
```

```
public class Scheduler
{
    public List<string> desks { get; set; }
    public List<string> employees { get; set; }

}
```

However, I don't know how to represent the `schedule` node, which is a nested dictionary of variable lengths.

- The **outer dictionary** maps an integer to an inner dictionary.
- The **inner dictionaries** maps a string to a string.

What kind of data structure could I use in C# to represent such a YAML structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working, but id be curious if there is a better way. I'm experienced with JSON deserialization but haven't had much YAML deserialization experience.

```
public class Scheduler
{
    public List<string> desks { get; set; }
    public List<string> employees { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<int, IDictionary<string,string>> schedule { get; set; }
}
```